# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages on laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Create a new project but its throws following error `sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` is used.

```
sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
[sudo] password for sevenbits11: 
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.0): Downloading (100%)         
Created project in blog
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.x-dev, 7.1.x-dev].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Which system do you use? So it depends upon your system, but you should install needed package for your system( maybe php-xml in this case)

Comment: system : Ubantu 16.04  PHP 7.0